# C stdin reads file infinitely

Tags: c, stdin, infinite

I have a basic C program that needs to read input from stdin. 
First, it reads from an input file by using

```
./Program <input
```

and then it loops through to read that until there's no more

```
while(scanf("%s",command)!=EOF){
    printf("%s\n",command);
}
```

After that I need to read from the keyboard again, but it continues infinitely to spam read the last line from my input file, not letting me use my keyboard for input.

```
 while(1){

 scanf("%s",command);
 if(!strcasecmp(command,"exit"))
  exitProg();
 else if(!strcasecmp(command,"help"))
  helpMess();
 else
  printf("Command \"%s\" not recognized, use command \"help\" for a list.\n",command);
 }
```

Comment: If you redirect standard input to a file, it is no longer connected to the terminal.

Comment: is there a way to direct it back to the keyboard?

Comment: On some platforms, yes (no standard method, however). I would however perhaps just take the initial file as an argument and read it with conventional methods (instead of redirecting anything).

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation for `scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/), specifically the part about the return value, excerpted below:

> ## Return Value
>
> On success, the function returns the number of items successfully read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens.
>   In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

The problem you're having is that once the file runs out of data, the program's standard-in does not revert back to the controlling terminal, it stays at the end of the empty file.  Your scanf call is silently failing, leaving the contents of `command` unmodified.  If you want to be able to read from both, you'd need to find another way of handling that.

It might be possible that your shell supports this functionality.

Comment: @jons34yp: Issues with your link, by category: 1. corrected (website's description has been updated) 2. they are subjectively similar 3a. bad practice does not mean incorrect 3b. cites only a blog. STL == standard template library. it's a real thing 3c. website documents old C stdlib in addition to C++ extensions. Those that pertain to C++ use <iostream>, etc 3d. don't know enough to say anything 4a. yes it does. read the pages for memcpy and memmove 4b. yes it does, read the atoi page 4c. I suspect this behavior is implementation specific. website does not specify how comparison is performed.

Comment: @jons34yp: if you shouldn't refer to a site because it's not perfect, then one might not want to refer to SO either. I think I'd argue that cplusplus.com is much more useful than not.

Comment: There must be at least a few misstatements in linux man pages.  By your logic, if there exist more than 4 of them, we shouldn't use those either.